# HTML верстка, меню выходит за пределы таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, меню, таблицы

Всем привет, есть код меню как здесь:

https://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

и есть таблица

```
<body leftmargin="0" 
      marginheight="0" 
      marginwidth="0" 
      rightmargin="0" 
      bottommargin="0" 
      topmargin="0" >
<table width="100%" 
       border="0" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       cellpadding="0" 
       height="100%" style="min-width: 780px;">...
```

при увеличении количества элементов меню, увеличивается вертикальная полоса прокрутки(и пустой экран - таблица остается на месте).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как заставить таблицу растягиваться?

Comment: а зачем вам атрибуты leftmargin и т.п.? Нельзя ли написать в CSS: `body: { margin: 0; }`?

Comment: пока этими атрибутами можно пренебречь, это код пока не на 100% готов

Comment: в некоторых порталах меню обрезается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в

```
<table width="100%" 
       border="0" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       cellpadding="0" 
       height="100%" style="min-width: 780px; overflow: hidden;">
```

добавил `overflow: hidden;`

и вроде-бы чтобы полностью решить надо графически рисовать "субконтейнера" с многоколонным списком